# How to Populate Textbox after GridView row clicked in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I have a GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridSearchResults" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="uid" runat="server"
    AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered"
    OnRowDataBound="gridSearchResults_RowDataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridSearchResults_UserSelected">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="uid" HeaderText="UID" SortExpression="uid" ItemStyle-Width="30%"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="givenName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="givenName" ItemStyle-Width="35%" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="sn" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="sn" ItemStyle-Width="35%" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

With `AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" a "select" button appears in every row.  I can click on this and fire:

```
`protected void gridSearchResults_UserSelected(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Get the user's ID from the selected row
    idNumber.Text = gridSearchResults.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    firstName.Text = gridSearchResults.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    lastName.Text = gridSearchResults.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
}
```

which works.  However, I would like to remove the "select" button and be able to press anywhere in the row to populate the TextBoxes.

This is the code for gridSearchResults_RowDataBound, which should handle the row click:

```
protected void gridSearchResults_RowDataBound(object objSender, GridViewRowEventArgs gridViewRowEventArgs) {
    if (gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        // Setup click handler and cursor
        //gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = DONT KNOW WHAT TO ADD HERE
        gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";

        // Implement row mouseover and mouseout
        gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.originalStyle=this.style.backgroundColor; this.style.backgroundColor='#B3E5FC';");
        gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalStyle;");
    }
}
```

I have seen something like `e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(grdSearchResults, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);` but I'm not sure how to mix the two.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is your working example, you have the information you want in the `gridSearchResults.SelectedRow.Cells` collection. In the modified event, have you tried to use instead `gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.Cells`?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If you want to remove the select button,  you can remove it from the aspx code. The `OnSelectedIndexChanged` would still work.

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found here; https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Selecting-GridView-Row-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-Row.aspx

For my solution I needed to modify a couple of things. In `gridSearchResults_RowDataBound` I need to add:

```
gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gridSearchResults, "Select$" + gridViewRowEventArgs.Row.RowIndex);
```

In `gridSearchResults_UserSelected` I needed to update the Cell indices.